# Value [i] is not being identified

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

```
times = {
 "times1": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times2": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times3": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times4": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times5": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times6": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times7": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times8": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"]
}
access = {
 "access1": [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,True],
 "access2": [False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True,True],
 "access3": [False,False,False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False],
 "access4": [True,True,False,True,True,True,False,False,True,True],
 "access5": [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,False],
 "access6": [True,False,False,True,True,False,True,True,False,True],
 "access7": [True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True],
 "access8": [True,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True,True]
}
askcourt = str(input("which court would you like to book? (1-8) "))
courtindextime = "times" + askcourt
courtindexacc = "access" + askcourt
for i in access[courtindexacc][i]:
#The i here goes unidentified for some reason
 if access[courtindexacc][i] == True:
   print("Court %s is available at: %s" %(askcourt, times[courtindextime][i]))
```

To my understanding [i] should be being identified as any value within the array called upon, however, this seems not to be working. If anyone could show me how to fix this I would be thankful.

Comment: Can you explain what you think `for i in access[courseindexacc][i]:` is supposed to do? You're creating an iteration variable by using that same iteration variable.

Comment: What is the end goal of this program? Are you trying to cross reference `access` with `times` to print times available for each `access` value?

Comment: Aside from the linked duplicate, please try reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements , or try putting `python tutorial for loop` into a search engine. Unless of course this was just a typo and you know it should just be `for i in access[courtindexacc]:`.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use variable i before assignment:

```
for i in access[courtindexacc][i]:
```

your code should be like this

```
for i in access[courtindexacc]:
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is undefined because it references itself in its initiation.

```py
for i in access[courtindexacc][i]:
    ^                          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

- Never change the value after `in` when you write a loop
- I think this code is actually you want to do:

```
times = {
 "times1": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times2": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times3": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times4": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times5": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times6": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times7": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
 "times8": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"]
}
access = {
 "access1": [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,True],
 "access2": [False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True,True],
 "access3": [False,False,False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False],
 "access4": [True,True,False,True,True,True,False,False,True,True],
 "access5": [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,False],
 "access6": [True,False,False,True,True,False,True,True,False,True],
 "access7": [True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True],
 "access8": [True,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True,True]
}
askcourt = str(input("which court would you like to book? (1-8) "))
courtindextime = "times" + askcourt
courtindexacc = "access" + askcourt
for time,permission in enumerate(access[courtindexacc]):
    if permission == True:
        print(f"Court {askcourt} is available at: {time+8}")
```

result:

```
which court would you like to book? (1-8) 1
Court 1 is available at: 8
Court 1 is available at: 11
Court 1 is available at: 12
Court 1 is available at: 16
Court 1 is available at: 17
```